# Total power of sine in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i'm trying to use `pwelch` or`periodogram` to get the power of a signal at different frequencies. As a test i tried a single sine:

```
sqrt(2)*sin(x)
```

It should has a power of one. However, my script shows different values in the plot and for the total power. What am i doing wrong and why are the spectra dependent of the number of samples `N`?

```
clc;
clear all;

fs=1e6;
fn=fs/2;
N=2^12;
df=fs/N;

t=0:1/fs:(N-1)/fs;

nu0=250e3;
nu0=df*floor(nu0/df);

a=sqrt(2);
x=a*sin(2*pi*nu0*t);

[px,f]=pwelch(x,[],0,[],fs);
%[px,f]=periodogram(x,[],[],fs);

semilogy(f,px);

disp(['Total power: ',num2str(sum(px))]);
```

EDIT: To clarify my question:
I got the expected result using:

```
f=0:df:fn-df;    
X=fft(x);
amp=(abs(X)./N).^2;
amp=2*amp(1:N/2);
amp(1)=amp(1)/2;

plot(f,pow2db(amp));
```

What is the difference to pwelch and periodogram?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `pwelch` and `periodogram` give power spectral **density**. To compute the **power** you need to **integrate** power spectral density with respect to frequency. Approximating the integral by a sum, this means that you need to multiply `sum(px)` by the frequency step:

```
sum(px) * (f(2)-f(1))
```

Or use `trapz` with two inputs to compute the integral numerically:

```
trapz(f, px)
```

In your example with `pwelch` this gives

```
>> [px,f]=pwelch(x,[],0,[],fs);
>> sum(px) * (f(2)-f(1))
ans =
   1.000000000000001
>> trapz(f, px)
ans =
   0.999999999999995
```

And with `periodogram`:

```
>> [px,f]=periodogram(x,[],[],fs);
>> sum(px) * (f(2)-f(1))
ans =
   1.000000000000000
>> trapz(f, px)
ans =
   1.000000000000000
```